# How to close MySQL workbench without killing the running query?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, procedure

I am running a very long procedure from MySQL workbench 6.1 and it has been running for quite a while now (so I can't just drop it and restart it later) and from my calculations it will probably run for a long while more.
I set the "connection drop" variable to a very big time, however I will have to turn off the computer before the end of that (so I can't just wait for it to time out).
The procedure doesn't return anything, so I don't really care about not receiving its result.
Is there a way to close workbench without having to stop the procedure from running?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there any way to travel `Antarctica` without `SHIP` or `PLANE` or `CAR` or `WALK`?

Comment: @VickyThakor: Sorry, I did not get what you said has to do with the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply said: no, it's not possible.

The running query is bound to a specific context: the connection from the client to server, which includes certain states (e.g. transaction, sql mode and others). Killing the client means to kill the connection. This will ultimatively kill any processing the server is doing for this client connection.

Comment: Thanks for answering.
Just for the record: I managed to do it by turning off my network from the notebook, once I did that MySQL didn't drop the procedure on the server and I could close the client sucessfully.

Comment: That is ... surprising. The server is supposed to auto close any client connection that does no longer respond. But maybe it's not checking the connection until the procedure was done. If so I learned something new.